# function foo(param) { alert("foo called"); } and $scope.foo = function(param){alert("foo");};

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, use-strict, unit-testing

> I think I am having a similar problem with AngularJS like many others.
>   I was fixing a previous error message (that I could not call
>   controller functions from within test describe blocks) and got new
>   errors.
>
> **Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fooController' is not a function, got undefined**
>
> I have read other post but still can't correct it.
>
> so my controller is like..
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['MyAppControllers']);
> var appControllers = angular.module('MyAppControllers', []);
>
> appControllers.controller('fooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
> function foo(param) {
>     alert("foo called");
> }
> }]);
> ```
>
> and my controllerspec is..
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> describe('fooController', function () {
>     var $scope, $controller;
>
>     beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
>         $scope = $rootScope.$new();
>         ctrl = $controller('fooController', { $scope: $scope });
>     }));
>
>     it("should write foo called", function () {
>         $scope.foo();
>    });
> });
> ```
>
> **why does it keep saying fooController is not a function??**
>
> Thanks you all.

## **Old Post edited. Would you please read the bottom post (my new question? :))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change controller

```
appControllers.controller('fooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

//add your function within scope
$scope.foo = function(){
 alert("foo called");
}
}]);
```

Comment: becuase 'use strict'; I cannot. Is there any other ways?

Comment: I tried to kill 'use strict'; and follow the suggestion. still the same error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

well. I was dumb. I didn't put after describe.

So I fixed the problem now with:

```
'use strict';

describe('fooController', function () {
    **beforeEach(module('MyApp'))**;
    var $scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('fooController', { $scope: $scope });
    }));

    it("should write foo called", function () {
        $scope.foo("aa");
    });
});
```

and controller..

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['MyAppControllers']);

var appControllers = angular.module('MyAppControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('fooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    function foo(param) {
        alert("foo called");
    }
}]);
```

I would like to ask about my original problem now if I could.

the problem is that function foo cannot be seen from controllerSpec's testing blocks
**TypeError: undefined is not a function**

I saw a post saying function is private and should turn the function into l

```
$scope.foo = function(param){alert("foo");};
```

But 'use strict' prohibits turning function like above.

I was wondering how others is doing about this problem?

Thank you again.

Comment: well, you could use '$scope.foo = function(param){alert("foo");};' this line under 'use strict'. I still don't know what was preventing this before.